# I don't understand why the compiler behaves this way

Tags: c++, reference

I was trying to "explore" different situations in c++ oop when dealing with references and something strange came up. The output is "31 20" and I did expected it to be this way.

Here is the complete version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Persoana {
public:
    int varsta;

    Persoana(int v = 30) : varsta(v) {}
};

class Profesor {
public:
    int marca = 100;
    int varsta;

    Profesor(int v = 20) : varsta(v) {}

    operator Persoana() {
        Persoana p;
        p.varsta = varsta;
        return p;
    }

};
Persoana f(Persoana &p){
    p.varsta++;
    return p;
}

int main(){
    Persoana p;
    f(p);
    cout<<endl<<p.varsta;
    Profesor prof;
    f((Persoana&)prof);
    cout<<" "<<prof.varsta;

    return 0;
}
```

However, real problem consists in this line:

```
f((Persoana&)prof);

//A p object is created which borrows prof's implicit values.
//The reference becomes formal and f function increments "marca"
```

Why did it modify "marca" so that its value is now 101 ?

Comment: You may not do that `(Persoana&)prof`, `prof` is not `Persoana`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Crank up the compiler diagnostics and you'll get a nice warning that you oughta not do that.: https://godbolt.org/z/q7Ysxq67G

Comment: It is something I found in an exam where I need to explain the output and its rationale.

Comment: @273K Probably a type conversion via `operator Profesor::Persoana()`.

Comment: Technically you can't explain it. You get Undefined Behaviour and as you can probably guess from the name, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've invoked undefined behavior by casting `prof` to a reference to an unrelated type, and passing it to something that uses that reference. Anything can happen. Never do this.

As for the observed behavior, in practice, for many compilers (including yours, apparently), `marca` gets modified because it's the first attribute of the object in question; `Persoana`'s `varsta` is located at the beginning of the storage for a `Persoana` object, and by lying to `f` about what you're passing, it tries to work with data of the same size, at the same offset, inside the `Profesor` object. The names of the attributes are *irrelevant*; those are eliminated during compilation anyway, so the compiled version of `f` is looking for "the `int`-sized thing at the beginning of the pointer it was passed", not for something specifically named `varsta`, and in a `Profesor`, that first thing is `marca`, so that's what gets modified.

Comment: In other words, member names in trivial classes are aliases for offsets into a classes' memory; `Profesor`and `Persoana` are unrelated types  which both have an `int` at the same offset 0, with the symbolic names `Persoana::varsta` and `Profesor::marca`, respectively. The memory at that offset is accessed with those names. Luckily, the offset for the unrelated `Persoana::varsta` and `Profesor::varsta` is different, or the program would appear to function as intended, and the error error would be hidden!

Comment: Couldn't have found a clearer explanation. Thank you very much! Dealing with such things is fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

The case is a bit tricky. Generally, your cast to "reference to `Profesor`" is a cast to an unrelated type. While you can do that, it is an error, and the result is undefined. The reason this is allowed at all is that the compiler, in general, may not be able to tell whether the types are indeed unrelated:

File 1:

```
struct S { int i; } s { 1 };
```

File 2:

```
struct S; // note: S's definition is unknown here
int f(S *ps) { int* pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(sp); return *pi; }
```

The above is legitimate (although brittle and C-style) code. The compiler must trust the coder about the reinterpret cast.

In your case though, the classes are indeed unrelated, and the program is ill-formed.

Something interesting happens when you change `f()` to take a const reference (thanks to 273K for the idea). Such a reference can bind to a temporary which will continue to exist as long as the const reference exists. That temporary can be constructed via the conversion function so that the program becomes valid. (Using `f()` s return value is also legit, even though the temporary has expired, because it is a true copy.)

I provided both functions and instrumented your code so that each function makes an output. I had to make `Persoana::varsa` mutable in order to change it through a const ref, which is fine; the object is not in read-only memory.

**Note in the output how the conversion function is invoked for the const reference but not for the regular reference.**

I also used the macro `offsetof()` to print the relative positions of the data members: `Profesor`'s `marca` resides at the same offset as `Persoana`'s `varsa`, which is the reason it is changed by the function which is tricked into thinking it's handling a `Persoana`.

Of course, the entire code handling the flawed reference conversion is ill-formed and might as well crash. But since the classes are simple data structures, and since `Persoana` is smaller than `Profesor`, the bad memory access "works" here.

Last not least let me remark that in a typical beginner OO lesson, a `Profesor`  would likely be a special person and as such inherit from `Persoana` instead of re-defining data members like `varsa`.

Here is the demonstration program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

class Persoana {
public:
    mutable int varsta;

    Persoana(int v = 30) : varsta(v) {}
};

class Profesor {
public:
    int marca = 100;
    int varsta;

    Profesor(int v = 20) : varsta(v) {}

    operator Persoana() {
        Persoana p;
        p.varsta = varsta;
        cout << "operator Persoana(): varsta == " << p.varsta << endl;
        return p;
    }

};

Persoana f(const Persoana& p) {
    p.varsta++;
    cout << "f(const Persoana& p): varsta incremented to " << p.varsta << endl;
    return p;
}

Persoana f(Persoana& p) {
    p.varsta++;
    cout << "f(Persoana& p) with NON-CONST argument: \"varsta\" incremented to " << p.varsta << endl;
    return p;
}

int main() {

    cout << "positions of members in the classes:\n"
        << "Persoana::varsta: " << offsetof(Persoana, varsta) << endl
        << "Profesor::marca: " << offsetof(Profesor, marca) << endl
        << "Profesor::varsta: " << offsetof(Profesor, varsta) << endl << endl;

    Profesor prof;
    cout << " -------- Test for f((const Persoana&)prof) ----------\n";
    cout << "varsta of prof: " << prof.varsta << endl;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // The conversion function Profesor::Persoana() 
        // will be invoked, producing a true
        // (though temporary) `Persoana` object. The const reference
        // will bind to that `Persoana` temporary object.
        // The user-defined conversion function is called implicitly:
        // No cast necessary!
        const Persoana& const_persoana_ref = prof; 
        cout << "varsta of temporary Persoana returned from f(const): " 
            << f(const_persoana_ref).varsta << endl;
    }
    // equally valid explicit conversion demonstration
    {
        const Persoana& const_persoana_ref2 = static_cast<const Persoana&>(prof);
    }
    cout << "varsta of prof: " << prof.varsta << endl;
    cout << "marca of prof: " << prof.marca << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // This does not compile:
    // Persoana& persoana_ref = prof;
    
    // Neither does this:
    // Persoana& persoana_ref = static_cast<Persoana &>(prof);
    
    // We must force the compiler to change the reference type 
    // with a  reinterpret_cast:
    Persoana& persoana_ref = reinterpret_cast<Persoana&>(prof);

    cout << " -------- Test for f((Persoana&)) (with non-const argument)\n";
    cout << "varsta of prof: " << prof.varsta << endl;
    // NO conversion Profesor::Persoana() will be invoked for f() argument; 
    // instead the compiler is tricked into thinking that f() gets a ref to Persoana
    // while the object is actually a Profesor. Consequently, when the code accesses
    // the int at offset 0, it changes the Profesor's marca, not varsa (varsa
    // is likely at offset 4 on a 32 bit system).
    cout << "varsta of Persoana returned from f(non-const): " << f(persoana_ref).varsta << endl;
    cout << "varsta of prof: " << prof.varsta << endl;  // unchanged!
    cout << "marca of prof: " << prof.marca << endl;    // oops: changed!
}
```